# Assigning a value to a certain field of a new RecordPage

Tags: c#

I'm creating a new RecordPage for a new record. I want to programmatically fill in some fields for this new record. However, when the page is created, I couldn't find a valid DBObject to fill.

```
MyCustomRecordPageType newPage = new MyCustomRecordPageType();
newPage.StartNewRecordMode();
newPage.TypedNewRecordForSave.FieldIWantToFill.NewValue = 1234; //
```

`NullReferenceException` because `TypedNewRecordForSave` is null

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after save the objects type DBObject creating therefore the newPage.TypedNewRecordForSave is NULL.
To present the default values on the fields you have to add it on FieldEntries, for example:

```
MyCustomRecordPageType newPage = new MyCustomRecordPageType();
newPage.StartNewRecordMode();
newPage.CityNameEntry.Value="New York";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your 'MyCustomRecordPageType' looks like. But i would says that their is no initializer for 'TypedNewRecordForSave' in it.

That Means you have to initilize it wheter in the class or in that code :

```
newPage.TypedNewRecordForSave = new IDonTKnowTheTypeOfThat();
newPage.TypedNewRecordForSave.FieldIWantToFill = NewValue;
```

Is that what you are looking for ?